# How to handle dollar ($) sign in JSON_VALUE path

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

We store data as a JSON string in our database.
Due to the use of Newtonsoft JSON, this data contains fields that have $ signs in the key.

Is it possible to query these fields using the JSON_VALUE function in MSSQL?

The query I tried throws exception *JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '$' is found at position 2.*

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.$type') FROM dbo.JsonTable
```

The JsonData looks like this:

```
{
   "$type": "Project.Classes.JsonType",
   "amount": 50
}
```

Comment: The fact that you need quotes is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server#path).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), you need to surround the key name with quotes, if the key name starts with a dollar sign or contains special characters such as spaces.

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"$type": "Project.Classes.JsonType", "amount": 50}'
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."$type"') AS JsonValue
```

Output:

```
------------------------ 
JsonValue
------------------------ 
Project.Classes.JsonType
```