# How to handle dollar sign ($) in JSON path for super type in redshift?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, special-characters

### Summary:

I am trying to extract the values from a json stored as a super in redshift.

### Context

This issue is near identical to the [question posted here for TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223081/how-to-handle-dollar-sign-in-json-value-path).
My schema:

```
user_id VARCHAR
properties SUPER
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "$os": "Mac OS X",
  "$browser": "Chrome",
  "token": "123x5"
}
```

I have this as a column in my table called `properties`.

### Desired behavior

I want to be able to retrieve the value `Mac OS X` from the `$os` key and store it in a `VARCHAR` column.

### What I've tried

I am able to retrieve the value for keys that do not have special characters in the following way:
`SELECT properties.token from clean`

I have referenced the following aws docs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-overview.html

Attempting to do the same

I have tried the following which haven't worked for me:

`SELECT properties.'\$os' from clean`

`SELECT properties.'$os' from clean`

`SELECT properties[$os] from clean`

`SELECT properties['\$os'] from clean`

Referencing the following docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest
I have also attempted to iterate over the super type using partisql:

```
select b.*
, pr
from base b, b.properties pr;
```

But this returns no rows.

I also tried the following:

```
select
    properties
    , properties.token
    , properties[0] praw0
    , properties[0].os os
    , properties[0][0] praw00
    , properties[0][0][0] praw000
from base
```

And this returned rows with value in the `properties` and `token` columns but nulls in all the other columns.

What am I missing? What else should I be trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use double quotes `""`

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_json
(
    user_id    VARCHAR,
    properties SUPER
);

INSERT INTO test_json VALUES (1,JSON_PARSE('{"$os": "Mac OS X", "$browser": "Chrome", "token": "123x5"}'));
SELECT properties."$os" from test_json

-- Output
"Mac OS X"
```